# codeigniter url redirect is not woking fine

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I newly uploaded my codeigniter project to the server. It's uploaded to a folder(app). Now it's redirection is not working. Always it redirects to home page.

folder path : http://domain.com/app

htaccess rule is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

How should I alter the rule according to the folder path.

Comment: You'll need to add the app directory before the `index.php`, so it will be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php/$1 [L]`. Then don't forget to update your `base_url` in the config.php too!

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem, do you use dreamhost or gandi hosting ?

Try it :

**In your .htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**In your application/config/config.php**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Enjoy :)